# How to exit a bash script after it starts a Python process?

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix, exec

I have a Python program that can update itself from a GitHub repository. When I activate the updating process, the Python script runs `updater.bash` script and kills itself. The bash script updates the program and then runs it again. But it keeps running despite I put `exit 0` in the end of the updater. So, every update creates another bash script that eats more resources.

How can I kill the script after it runs the Python script?

Comment: run python script in background using nohup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec python ...` to replace bash with python program.

See: `help exec`